# Windows Authentication - Set Roles with custom criteria

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-authentication

I have started developing an intranet website using ASP.NET Web Forms (I'm a total beginner) that uses Windows Authentication to identify users, but to control access to various pages, I'm looking to assign roles to users based on set criteria based on data within SQL tables (this data can change daily).

So far, I have the 'out of the box' ASP.NET Web Forms template with Windows Authentication that has a working connection to my (remote) SQL Server database.

I apologise if this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't seem to find a solution that fits my needs.

Using some basic IF logic, I will have the following roles: 'Admin', 'Moderator', 'HRA', 'Manager' and 'Employee'.

Looking up the logged-in user's data from a SQL table (3-4 fields max), set criteria will determine the user's role as follows:

```
if (UserRole === null) Then
    If (ORG_ID === 30001000) Then
        UserRole === 'Admin'

    else if (ORG_ID === 30001001) Then
        UserRole === 'Moderator'

    else if (ORG_ID === 30001002) Then
        UserRole === 'HRA'

    else if (CHIEF === 'Chief') Then
        UserRole === 'Manager'

    else
        UserRole === 'Employee'
    End If
End if
```

I'm guessing that this would be worked into the Site.Master file that runs once per session but I'm stuck as to how this would work exactly and if anything needs to be added to the config file etc.

Thanks in advance, I understand how this would work with php but ASP.NET and how it works is completely new to me. If there is a better solution then great!

It's also worth noting that some parts of my site (e.g a Dashboards section) will allow some UserRoles to control custom access to dashboards controlled by an SQL table - but I can look at this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd answer this myself just incase it's of any use to anyone else. I implemented my own Custom Role Provider and connecting to sql data to assign roles like this:

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            var roles = GetRolesForUser(username);
            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (role.Equals(roleName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            //create our List to hold our Roles
            List<string> r = new List<string>();

            r.Add("Employee");

            //get our sap number of current user to look up against the database
            var persno = Int32.Parse(10 + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Length - 5));

            //connect to our sql database
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hrssportalConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
            string str;
            SqlCommand com;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();

            //SQL Query
            str = "SELECT org_publisher.persno, org_publisher.record_type, org_publisher.org_string, map_user_roles.role_name FROM org_publisher LEFT JOIN users ON org_publisher.persno = users.persno LEFT JOIN map_user_roles ON users.role_id = map_user_roles.role_id WHERE org_publisher.persno = " + persno;
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

            //get our data
            //SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            //reader.Read();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());

            //if we have rows returned do our checks
            if (dt != null)
            {

                //get our data for checking
                //string org_string = reader["org_string"].ToString();
                //string line_manager = reader["record_type"].ToString();

                string org_string = dt.Rows[0]["org_string"].ToString();
                string line_manager = dt.Rows[0]["record_type"].ToString();

                //Line Manager Role check
                if (line_manager == "<ChiefPosition>")
                {
                    r.Add("Manager");
                }

                //HRSS Role Check
                if (org_string.Contains("30001803"))
                {
                    r.Add("HRSS");
                }

                //HRA Role Check
                if (org_string.Contains("30003237"))
                {
                    r.Add("HRA");
                }

                //add all custom roles by cycling through rows
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["role_name"].ToString() != null)
                        {
                            r.Add(row["role_name"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }

                //close our sql objects
                dt.Dispose();
                con.Close();

                //return List as an array
                string[] rolesArray = r.ToArray();
                return rolesArray;
            }
            else
            {
                //if no Rows returned from SQL, return only Employee role from List
                string[] rolesArray = r.ToArray();
                return rolesArray;
            }
        }

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {

        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in web.config:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="ClassLibrary.CustomRoleProvider"
    applicationName="WebApplication1" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```